# How to continue from the last id in sqlite db? (includes recyclerview)

Tags: sqlite, android-recyclerview

As you know well if i delete entries from a db or completely clear that db,   id is autoincremented from where it is left. How can I prevent this- I mean I want my database dont erase the last id's for example even id=2 is removed next id should be id=3. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `id` field `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`.  That should prevent re-use of id values.  (See https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)